# VBA to return the occurrence of a name in a list

Tags: excel, vba

What im trying to achieve is the following in excel:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeOos.png)

So what i need to do is list the occurrence of cat and dog based on the index (a or b). I have a large amount of data that i need to do this on

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `=COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,A1,B$1:B1,B1)` for C1 and then simply auto fill down as you need it?

Answer (score 1):

In lieu of vba you can use pivot.. create a pivot based on column 1 and column 2 and set the value of pivot as count of column 2.... u can then make the pivot range dynamic by using offset function to adjust automatically as per the height of the table....

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a function?
=> Countif(A1:A15,"Cat")

Adjust the function the way you need it and it should output the number of occurrences.
It is even possible to combine multiple criteria.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

Hope this helps